# Filter on redirect does not load styling

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters

I am trying to create a filter that makes sure the user is logged in before going to any other page

Here I have 2 issues (that I know of).

<s>1) I am having issues with only allowing jsp files. When I try to access my page tomcat throws an error</s>

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> /public/*.jsp in filter mapping
```

but when my url mapping is /public/* it sorta works as intended

**EDIT 1:** Turns out I am using an incorrect mapping, thanks to some comments below, for anyone coming to this page here is that part of the solution: http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html

2) When I did get a redirect with `/public/*` I was able to get to my login page, but all of the styling was missing

Here is my filter in web.xml

**EDIT2:** The code snippets below now reflect changes I have made regarding answers

`<filter>
      <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>authentication.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`

This is what I am attempting in my filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        // Get the requested address
        String from = URLEncoder.encode(req.getRequestURI(), "UTF-8");

        if(req.getQueryString() != null){
            from += "?" + req.getQueryString();
        }
        System.err.println("from str: " + from);
        System.out.println("Serv path: " + req.getServletPath());
        if(!req.getServletPath().startsWith("/public/login")){
            if(session == null || session.getAttribute("username") == null){
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/public/login.jsp?from="+from);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Username: " + session.getAttribute("username"));
                // pass the request along the filter chain
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions for improvements to my filter?

Comment: You should go through the Servlet specification on valid URL mappings.

Comment: Keep in mind that /*.jsp excludes any query string in the URL rendering your app unsecure.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis would you be able to provide a link?

Comment: @user2793390, what would be a better alternative using a filter and making sure my app is secure?

Comment: @Vnge You must likley want to use /public/* instead of /public/*.jsp. On another note, it might be easier to just use some framework like Spring Security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL pattern is not a true glob match and only supports two types of wildcards: `/someting/*` and `*.something`

http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html

When it comes to styling you have to allow the resources (CSS, Javascript, images etc) used by the login page to be loaded without a session the same way you allow access to the login page itself.

Comment: that makes sense for one issue i was having

Comment: See edited answer for explanation about why styling is not loaded

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Use your existing code, just remove .jsp from the if. E.g. if(!req.getServletPath().startsWith("/public/login"))) ...

Then make sure the login.jsp only loads CSS, images and JS from /public/login e.g. <img ... src="login/logo.jpg" ... />

Comment: Another way is to just apply your filter to *.jsp but that will make everything that is not a JSP available for the world and will require login for all JSP-s not just the ones under /public

Comment: all of my jsps are in public any way, I will try your first suggestion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49188/discussion-between-vnge-and-anttix)